# No HD claim in token response

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth, firebaseui

Following the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters) on how to restrict sign in to G Suite domains, it says to verify the ID tokens 'hd' claims, and the existence thereof.

I have the following specified in my Firebase Auth UI config client side:

```
signInOptions: [
          {
            provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            customParameters: { hd: "*" }
          },
          ...
        ],
```

Which correctly show the login options for all G Suite domains. But when checking the idToken server side with `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)` the response returned does not include a `hd` claim. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Does it matter that the ID token does not contain the `hd` claim? the ID token will contain a claim with the user's email. You can check the domain of the email in that case.

Comment: It does, since I only want to allow G Suite domains (I.e. not @gmail.com etc.).

Comment: You enforce the check by checking the email domain in the ID token. If your `hd` is `example.com`, then the email should look like `user@example.com`. You can enforce that in your security rules or by checking the ID token claims server side, if you are using your own server. If the domain doesn't match, then you reject the request.

Comment: My problem is i don't know what domain they will be signing in with, hence the wildcard HD claim. I just need to make sure they come from a hosted domain and not a @gmail etc.

Comment: @Chris sounds like you want a domain blacklist (no @gmail.com) instead of a GSuite whitelist?